# how to change button url in default verification email template in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

the button now when I click says 404 not found I want it to go to /en/home but it goes to /home how to change the URL in the default email template button

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the path in the `VerificationController.php` (or your custom created controller file) available under `Your Project > app > Http > Controllers` dirctory.

On opening it with an editor you'll see `protected $redirectTo = '/home';`.

Update the path with your value as:

`protected $redirectTo = '/en/home';`

Comment: it still says 404 not found when i click verify email address button

Comment: have you defined the route in your ``routes/web.php`` file?

Comment: can I see your ``routes/web.php`` file contents?

Comment: Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect()->route('home' , app()->getLocale());
});

Route::get('{lang}/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Comment: try opening ``yoursite.com/en/home`` in your browser. Does it open or it returns 404?

Comment: What? It's opening or returning 404?

Comment: it opens my home page no errors , the only problem is with the email template

Comment: Okay, I see. Run ``php artisan route:cache`` and ``php artisan cache:clear`` in your project and try again. and let me know.

Comment: You seem to be doing somewhere wrong then. Add your ``VerificationController.php`` file

Answer (score 0):

change `RouteServiceProvider::HOME` constant to whatever path you want redirected to after auth operation.